# How to add and remove single-index dataframe rows to and from a MultiIndex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a df, `Stock_to_buy`, that tells which stock to buy on a given date. Index column is `Date`.

```
             Symbol   Shares
Date         
2018-01-01   AAOI     20
2018-01-03   FB       34
2018-01-05   AMZN     5
2018-01-07   SQ       25
2018-01-08   TPL      31
```

I created another df, `Portfolio`. I guess the solution requires it to be MultiIndex, so the index columns are `Date` and `Symbol`.

```
                       Shares
Date         Symbol
2018-01-01   NaN       NaN
2018-01-02   NaN       NaN
2018-01-03   NaN       NaN
2018-01-04   NaN       NaN
2018-01-05   NaN       NaN
2018-01-06   NaN       NaN
2018-01-07   NaN       NaN
2018-01-08   NaN       NaN
```

I want to update `Portfolio` based on `Stock_to_buy`: If a Symbol is in `Stock_to_buy` on a given date, it should be added as a row to `Portfolio` on that date, and it should be kept there on subsequent dates until the `Sell_Next_Day` becomes `True`, in which case the row of the `Symbol` should be removed from subsequent dates. Below is a sample, how I want `Portfolio` to work.

```
                      Shares   Sell_Next_Day
Date         Symbol
2017-12-31   NaN      NaN      NaN 
---------------------------------------------        
2018-01-01   AAOI     20       False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-02   AAOI     20       False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-03   AAOI     20       False
             FB       34       False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-04   AAOI     20       False
             FB       34       False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-05   AAOI     20       False
             FB       34       False
             AMZN     5        False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-06   AAOI     20       True           # AAOI will be sold next day
             FB       34       False
             AMZN     5        False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-07   FB       34       False
             AMZN     5        True           # AMZN will be sold next day
             SQ       25       False
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-08   FB       34       False
             SQ       25       False
             TPL      31       False
```

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the second DataFrame you create.  Also, how do we know when `sell_next_day` becomes True?

Comment: It has more date entries than `Stock_to_buy`. `Sell_Next_Day` is calculated based on open,high,low,close. I just wanted to make the sample simple.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but it's unclear *why* it has more, and it's also unclear where you are getting `sell_next_day` from

Comment: `Stock_to_buy` is a result of a manipulation of a huge dataframe and I would like `Portfolio` to be a separte one. `Sell_Next_Day` will be calculated based on other metrics that are included in the rows of `Stock_to_buy`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best setup. That aside, you basically want to use `df.append` to add `Date`, `Symbol` and `Shares` to your second df.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is exactly what you want, but I think it can be helpful.
**Data:**

```
Stock_to_buy = pd.DataFrame(data=[
                                  ['2018-01-01','AAOI','20'],
                                  ['2018-01-03', 'FB', 34],
                                  ['2018-01-05', 'AMZN' , 5],
                                  ['2018-01-07', 'SQ', 25],
                                  ['2018-01-08', 'TPL' ,31]
                            ], columns=['Date', 'Symbol','Shares']
                           )
Stock_to_buy.Date = pd.to_datetime(Stock_to_buy.Date)
```

**Step 1.** Fill all possible values.

```
END_DATE = Stock_to_buy.sort_values('Date').Date.values[-1]
def fill(df):
    index = pd.date_range(start=df.Date.values[0], end=END_DATE)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[[1]*len(index)], index=index)

Portfolio = Stock_to_buy.groupby(['Symbol', 'Shares']
                    ).apply(fill).reset_index(
                    ).drop([i for i in range(0,8)], 1).rename(
                    columns={'level_2': 'Date'}).set_index('Date')
```

Output:

```
           Symbol Shares
Date                    
2018-01-01   AAOI     20
2018-01-02   AAOI     20
2018-01-03   AAOI     20
2018-01-04   AAOI     20
2018-01-05   AAOI     20
2018-01-06   AAOI     20
2018-01-07   AAOI     20
2018-01-08   AAOI     20
2018-01-05   AMZN      5
2018-01-06   AMZN      5
2018-01-07   AMZN      5
2018-01-08   AMZN      5
2018-01-03     FB     34
2018-01-04     FB     34
2018-01-05     FB     34
2018-01-06     FB     34
2018-01-07     FB     34
2018-01-08     FB     34
2018-01-07     SQ     25
2018-01-08     SQ     25
2018-01-08    TPL     31
```

**Step 2.** If we have column Sell_Next_Day, like:

```
Sell_Next_Day = pd.Series([False, False, False, False, False, True, False, 
                           False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False,
                           False,False,False, False, False, False],
                           name='Sell_Next_Day')
```

Then we can join them and drop all next raws after `Symbol` has True value in `Sell_Next_Day`.

```
def drop_dates(df):
    if df.Sell_Next_Day.any():
        res = df[df.Date <= df[df.Sell_Next_Day == True].Date.values[0]]
    else:
        res = df
    return res

Portfolio = Portfolio.reset_index().join(Sell_Next_Day
                            ).groupby('Symbol'
                            ).apply(drop_dates).set_index('Date')
```

Output:

```
           Symbol Shares  Sell_Next_Day
Date                                   
2018-01-01   AAOI     20          False
2018-01-02   AAOI     20          False
2018-01-03   AAOI     20          False
2018-01-04   AAOI     20          False
2018-01-05   AAOI     20          False
2018-01-06   AAOI     20           True
2018-01-05   AMZN      5          False
2018-01-06   AMZN      5          False
2018-01-07   AMZN      5           True
2018-01-03     FB     34          False
2018-01-04     FB     34          False
2018-01-05     FB     34          False
2018-01-06     FB     34          False
2018-01-07     FB     34          False
2018-01-08     FB     34          False
2018-01-07     SQ     25          False
2018-01-08     SQ     25          False
2018-01-08    TPL     31          False
```

Is it what you want?